# Tripurāri pūrṇima festival story and its significance?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, tradition, festivals, celebrations

The other names of Tripurāri  Pournami are  **Tripurī  pūrṇima, Karthika Pūrṇima, Deva Deepāwali or Deva Diwāli, or Tripurāri pūrṇima.**

My questions are: -

- Why do we celebrate Karthika or Tripurāri paurṇima  Festival?
- What are the stories associated with it?
- In what different ways it is celebrated across India ?

Answer (score 2):

Full moon day (Purnima) in the month of Kartik in a traditional Hindu calendar is called Kartik pournima , also known as Tripurari pournima ,Dev Diwali. Dev Deepavali is the Diwali of the Devas or Gods held on the Kartik pournima as It is believed that **on the day of Dev Deepavali, the** **Gods descend on Earth**. Tulsi Vivah is also carried out this day.

An important ritual on the day is the **lighting of Diyas** (lamps) after the sighting of the moon. In some parts **"Tripurasur Dahan"** (Burning) is also carried out.

Kartik Snan (Holy bathing)  and Deepdaan are main rituals performed during Dev Diwali. At the time of sunrise devotees do **Kartik Snan** and in the evenings they perform **Deepotsav**.

During this  Dev Diwali, a also a cultural festival called ‘**Ganga Mahotsav** is celebrated in **Varanasi**. Prabodhini Ekadashi is the important day in these celebrations. Thousands  of people visit Dasaswamedh Ghat to see liting of thousands of Diyas (earthen lamps) this is a tribute to river Ganga by people of Varanasi.

**Stories associeated with Tripurari Pournima or Kartik pournima -**

It's said that **Lord Vishnu returned to Vaikunta**, his abode, on this day after the **Vamana incarnation** and visiting King Bali. Kartik Poornima is closely associated with **Prabodhini ekadashi** ,  which marks the end of Chaturmas , a four-month period when Vishnu is believed to sleep. **Prabodhini Ekadashi signifies the awakening of the god.**

Kartik Purnima is also celebrated as the birth of Lord **Vishnu's first incarnation, the Matsya (fish) avatar**. It is also the birthday of Vrinda (Tulsi plant) and of Lord **Kartikeya, the son of Lord  Shiva.**

Another story is that **Lord Shiva** killed three demons, who spreading Adharma and killing innocent people, and destroyed the three cities built by the demons on Dev Diwali day. **Therefore the day is also known as Tripurari Purnima.**

**We find this story in ShreemadBhagvatam  - (7 skanda chapter -10 shloka 53-70)**

> **अथानुगृह्य भगवन्म भैशेष्ट इति सूरान्विभु: ।**  
>  
> **शरं धनुषि सन्धाय पुरेष्वस्त्रं व्यमुश्र्चत ।।57।।**
>
> **Meaning** - On hearing their request , **Lord Shankara** told the Gods "Do not fear" .Then he shot arow towards **these 3 cities.**
>
> [**SB 7.10.57**](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/10/57)
>
> **एवं दध्वा पुरस्तिस्त्रो भगवान्पुरहा नृप ।**  
>  
> **ब्रह्मादिभि: स्तुयमान: स्वधाम प्रत्यपद्यत ।।70।।**
>
> **Meaning** - O Yudhishthira , thus by burning those 3 cities , **Bhagvan shankar became "Tripurari"** & went to his abode with hearing
> the praising by Brahmadeva etc.
> .
>  [**SB 7.10.69**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/10/69)